# Tomato plant leaves becoming miscoloured and wilting

Tags: leaves, tomatoes, wilting

Suddenly most of the leaves on my tomato plant has become this kind of miscoloured, turning soft and curling to the point of wilting.

I'm not quite sure what is happenning, although it seems to have hit most of the leaves on the plant.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: I've not seen that before, but looking online this looks very much like some kind of blight.  What country/area are you in, and what is the humidity like?